# How to know whether Border as reached end of the page and if so i need to disable the thickness in xaml

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I am using a border inside the grid. I need to know how to find the end of the        page and if i find,i need to disable the thickness is it possible through xaml.

My code
`<Border  Margin="0,2,0,5"="green" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"/>`

Comment: What's your mean of 'disable the thickness'? set thickness to 0?

Comment: when the border reaches the end of the page ,thickness should not appear.else the border should appear